# Как добавить хэштеги перед каждой меткой (the_tags();)?

Tags: wordpress

Как в wp реализовать, чтобы на стр записи теги выводились с хэштегом. В стандартной документации решения нет, можно только разделять символами.

Пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте фильтр

```
function term_links_filter( $links ) {
    foreach ( $links as $key => $link ) {
        $links[ $key ] = str_replace( '" rel="tag">', '" rel="tag">#', $link );
    }

    return $links;
}

add_filter( 'term_links-post_tag', 'term_links_filter' );
```

Comment: Спасибо, почему то не сработало (

Comment: "Не работает" - самое худшее описание проблемы из возможных

Comment: Я добавил ваш код в functions.php , зашел на страницу поста, но хэштеги не применились.

Comment: Поправил ответ, протестировал - работает.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Вот бы еще вместо пробелов нижнее подчеркивание сделать к хэшам. Или хотя бы дефис